# Laravel Find tag in post

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I have in post many tags defined.
I cycle the posts to each one and I am trying check the tags if contain specific name - for example 'car'.

```
$post->tags
```

return me in cycle

```
Collection {#346 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
0 => Tag {#353 ▼
  #fillable: array:1 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:4 [▶]
  #original: array:8 [▶]
  #relations: array:1 [▶]
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
1 => Tag {#352 ▶}
]
}
```

How I can check the tag name?

Comment: do this   `dd($post->tags->toarray())` this will show you the result in an array(to make it easier to visualise the output, this is just for test) , then you just do a foreach to iterate over each element just like @mannil wrote.

Comment: Thank you for tip. it returns array well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through all tags using a `foreach` loop. I assume that your `Tag` object has a name attribute you can refer to. A code example would be:

```
foreach($post->tags as $tag){
    if($tag->name == "THENAMEYOUARELOOKINGFOR"){
         //do sth. here
    }
}
```

In case you want to use the `in_array` method, you can convert your collection so that there will be an array containing only the tag names.

```
$nameArray = $posts->tags->pluck('name')->all();
//Now you can use in_array
if(in_array("YOURSTRING", $nameArray)){
    //do sth.
}
```

Comment: I am searching for function like in_array(). I am surprised, if this cannot be done with easy way.

Comment: @Maximi You can use the in_array() method, but it'll be a bit more complicated. I'm updating my answer ;)

Comment: Ok, now i see it well. But which one is faster?

Comment: @Maximi I don't know which one is faster. Guess you have to try it out.

Comment: Me thought is foreach is better, because it will stop in first find. But not sure about performance. Especially pluck. Anyway, my issue seems solved.

Comment: Sound reasonable. Happy that I could help!

Comment: i think both are the same, since in array is a linear search (it does the same as the for each, it compares from value 1 till it find the needed result), to improve this you can get data sorted from the db then use  Binary search algorithm or something similar(if u want better performance)